# dygraph annotation icon clipped

Tags: annotations, icons, dygraphs, clipped

I have a dygraph with annotations using icons. I see that the bottom two pixel rows of the icon are clipped or drawn over when they are applied to the chart (icons are applied to the series, I haven't tried attachToBottom).

The tickHeight is set to 10, but the icon clipping problem occurs no matter what I do with tickHeight. I tried mis-reporting the icon height by +2 but that was ineffective. I have had to add two transparent rows to the bottom of my icons so that they appear correct on the graph.

Am I doing something wrong or is this an actual bug in dygraph annotations?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a demo link, preferably via dygraphs.com/fiddle or dygraphs.com/jsbin.

Comment: I've fiddled around with this for a while and can't reproduce it.  It occurs to me this may be some issue with bootstrap or another css somewhere in my project.  I'll work on that idea for a while.